# Starting/Restarting nginx from homebrew causes instant crash with no logs

Tags: nginx, homebrew

Homebrew is located at `/opt/homebrew`

[Homebrew services list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ9fX.png) upon restarting nginx. Strange thing is, there are no logs generated. This is after I freshly `brew uninstall nginx` and then `brew install nginx`. The `/opt/homebrew/var/log/nginx` directory is newly created by the reinstall, but remains empty.

Any idea what might be going on, or what to look into?

Thanks!

Expected nginx to start and stay up, but it instantly crashes with no error logs.

Tried uninstalling/reinstalling (including deleting the nginx log folder before reinstall), restarted my Mac (M1 Max).

Tried checking logs, but there are no logs.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue:

1. Ran nginx in the foreground to find out what was going on: `nginx -g 'daemon off;'`
2. Oh! The port is already bound... but by what... `sudo lsof -i :8080`
3. By nginx? Huh, by who... `ps aux | grep nginx`
4. By 'nobody' apparently. Still not sure what's up there, but ok, killing all extent nginx processes... `sudo nginx -s stop`
5. And restart nginx again... `brew services restart nginx`. And we're good!

Still not sure though why the logs were empty, if someone could shed light on that?